# Cannot able to request the localhost node server with HTML page using fetch API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, fetch-api

**Description:**

I am trying to send JSON data from an HTML page to the Node.js server running locally on port 5000 using Fetch API.

**Getting Error:**

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/attend' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**port error:**

POST http://localhost:5000/attend net::ERR_FAILED

**Fetch error:**

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

[Code Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB0ix.jpg)

**Node.js Code:**

```
  connectdb();
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.json({extended: false}));
    app.use (bodyParser.json());
    
    
    app.get('/',(req,res)=> res.send('API RUNNING'));
    
    app.post('/attend',async (req,res)=>{
        const {name,rollnumber} = req.body;
        console.log(name);
        console.log(rollnumber);
        try {
            let data = await Database.findOne({ rollnumber });
            if (data) {
                return res
                  .status(400)
                  .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'attandence is marked all ready' }] });
              }
              const  Data = new Database({
                rollnumber,
                name
              });
              await Data.save();
              res.json("added success fully");
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
    });
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Marked</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Client/style.css">
    <script>

     function attend(){
      const data = {
        name:'Syed Ali Shahzil',
        rollnumber:'180996'  
    };
    const options = {
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/attend',options);  
    }
 
  
  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a  href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="marked.html">attendence Marked</a></li>
           
          </ul>
          <button class="button" onclick="attend()"> Present</button>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to add some context to _why_ this is happening: This CORS error is to be expected, because your origin domain (`http://127.0.0.1:5501`) does not match your destination domain (`http://localhost:5000`). Yes, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are synonymous, but even a difference in port number will trigger the error. See: [Same Origin Policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do install the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your package by

```
$ npm install cors
```

And use it in your app

```
// Import cors
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

// Add it in the middleware
app.use(cors())
... Rest of your code
```

Your requests will work fine after that.